# Value Error: Input shape error in Keras Image captioning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to Machine Learning and I've been working on [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-a-deep-learning-caption-generation-model-in-python/#comment-429456) tutorial for sometime and it needs more than 45GB of RAM to run. So I've tried progressive Loading from [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-photo-caption-dataset-training-deep-learning-model/#comment-429458) tutorial.

Here is the error what i'm getting
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (13, 224, 224, 3)

here the model function

```
# define the captioning model
def define_model(vocab_size, max_length):
    # feature extractor model
    inputs1 = Input(shape=(4096,))
    fe1 = Dropout(0.5)(inputs1)
    fe2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)
    # sequence model
    inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
    se1 = Embedding(vocab_size, 256, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
    se2 = Dropout(0.5)(se1)
    se3 = LSTM(256)(se2)
    # decoder model
    decoder1 = add([fe2, se3])
    decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
    outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
    # tie it together [image, seq] [word]
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    # summarize model
    print(model.summary())
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
    return model
```

loading_photo function

```
# load a single photo intended as input for the VGG feature extractor model
def load_photo(filename):
    image = load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224))
    # convert the image pixels to a numpy array
    image = img_to_array(image)
    # reshape data for the model
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
    # prepare the image for the VGG model
    image = preprocess_input(image)[0]
    # get image id
    image_id = filename.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    return image, image_id
```

create_sequences and data_generator functions

```
# create sequences of images, input sequences and output words for an image
def create_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, desc, image):
    Ximages, XSeq, y = list(), list(),list()
    vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
    # integer encode the description
    seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([desc])[0]
    # split one sequence into multiple X,y pairs
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        # select
        in_seq, out_seq = seq[:i], seq[i]
        # pad input sequence
        in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq], maxlen=max_length)[0]
        # encode output sequence
        out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=vocab_size)[0]
        # store
        Ximages.append(image)
        XSeq.append(in_seq)
        y.append(out_seq)
    Ximages, XSeq, y = array(Ximages), array(XSeq), array(y)
    return [Ximages, XSeq, y]

# data generator, intended to be used in a call to model.fit_generator()
def data_generator(descriptions, tokenizer, max_length):
    # loop for ever over images
    directory = 'Flicker8k_Dataset'
    while 1:
        for name in listdir(directory):
            # load an image from file
            filename = directory + '/' + name
            image, image_id = load_photo(filename)
            # create word sequences
            desc = descriptions[image_id]
            in_img, in_seq, out_word = create_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, desc, image)
            yield [[in_img, in_seq], out_word]
```

and finally

```
model = define_model(vocab_size, max_length)
# define checkpoint callback
filepath = 'model-ep{epoch:03d}-loss{loss:.3f}-val_loss{val_loss:.3f}.h5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
# fit model
model.fit_generator(data_generator(descriptions, tokenizer, max_length), steps_per_epoch=70000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that although the input data consists of 13 images of (224, 224, 3) shape, the input layer for the feature extractor model accepts a 4096-length vector.

To fix the problem, first you must reshape the images to 1D in `def load_photo(filename):`

```
image = image.reshape((1, 224*224*3))
```

Then in `def define_model(vocab_size, max_length):`,

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(224*224*3, ))
```

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (13, 4485) 

Got this error :(

Comment: that fixed the problem for now. Thank you very much. I'll update as the training goes on.

Comment: 1861/70000 [..............................] - ETA: 4:34:10 - loss: 16.0335Traceback (most recent call last):

Got this error at 1861st step
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (150528,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: excuse me can you help in this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225332/invalid-argument-in0-mismatch-in1-shape